# Insert a pair into a map and increase the count?

Tags: c++, dictionary, std-pair

The codebase I'm working in uses the `map::operator[]` to insert *and* increment the count of items in that entry by one (this is a knowledge gap for me). Here's an example:

```
map<string, size_t> namesMap;
namesMap[firstName]++;
```

What I want to do is tack on an ID to the insert while retaining the increment behavior in the syntax above.

My new map would look like this:

```
map<string, pair<int, size_t>> namesMapWithID;
```

I'm struggling to see how to get the equivalent functionality with my new map. This is basically my goal (obviously wrong since "++" cannot be used this way):

```
namesMapWithID.insert(firstName, make_pair(employeeID, ++));
```

Is there a better approach that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via using the insert method along with the it/bool pair it returns, thereby delivering a single lookup (by name), setting the employee id if on the initial lookup, and then incrementing the counter respectively.

Something like this:

```
auto pr = namesMapWithID.insert(std::make_pair(firstName,
    std::make_pair(employeeID, size_t())));
++pr.first->second.second;
```

Comment: Ah, okay that's exactly what I was trying to do. I think I was hung up on just how much is going on under the hood with the [] operator.

Comment: @NeatoBandito Whether this is the correct application for the problem you're *really* trying to solve notwithstanding, it solves what you're asking, which I hope is enough. (apparently it wasn't for the anonymous down-voter).

Comment: Yes, the concept is what I was after. This was just something I came up with to illustrate it. Thanks for teaching me something new.